# Restriction of a convex function to {0, 1}^n

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-geometry, submodularity, convex-hull

Suppose I have a real-valued *convex* function $f$ on the unit hypercube $[0,1]^n$, and let $\bar{f}$ be its restriction to the integer points $\{0,1\}^n$. Does $\bar{f}$ satisfy any properties, or can any function on $\{0,1\}^n$ be obtained as a restriction of a convex function?

Comment: Any real valued function $g$ defined on $\{0,1\}^n$ can be extended to a convex function over $[0,1]^n$ (it is called the convex closure). The implication for your question is that indeed $\bar{f}$ will not have any specific properties.

Comment: Converted comment into an answer and added link to Dughmi's survey so that the question can essentially be closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any real valued function $g$ defined on $\{0,1\}^n$ can be extended to a convex function over $[0,1]^n$ (it is called the convex closure). See Dughmi's nice [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0322). The implication for your question is that indeed $\bar{f}$ will not have any specific properties.

Comment: But not necessarily extendible beyond [0,1]^n, right?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think you're right. I thought I recalled some paper with the condition on an $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ *having* a convex extension, but now I think it was probably *any* such convex extension.

Comment: Multilinear extension is not necessarily convex. We considered multilinear extension for submodular functions but it is neither convex nor concave. See for instance Jan Vondrak's thesis https://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/data/KAM_thesis.pdf. I am not sure if there are other notions of multilinear extensions.

Comment: One should be able to extend the convex function from $[0,1]^n$ to all of the space by making it become very steep outside the cube - this is typically done in convex optimization though there may be some technical details to be a bit careful about.

Comment: Yeah, in this case we can directly extend it to a convex function on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ because the convex closure will be "polyhedral" -- the pointwise maximum of a finite set of affine functions, i.e. $\bar{f}(x) = \max_{j \in J} h_j(x)$. Here affine = linear + constant. Each of those affine functions $h_j$ extends to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the definition of $\bar{f}$ does too.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri Sorry, you are right. For some reason I thought that the restriction of a multilinear function to a line is linear, but that’s nonsense (it only holds for affine functions).